# Git fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /home) Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set)

Tags: git, github

I did a `git pull` on my repo and ever since I've done so I've been getting errors anything I do anything with git. The error I typically get is:

```
fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /home)
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
```

Any idea what is causing this?

Comment: please check if you are in the correct folder

Answer (score 5):

You are calling `git pull` on not a git repository.

First initialize the repo as:

```
git init
```

Then add your repo origin as:

```
git remote add origin <url of repo>
```

Then call `git pull` or push your code.

Comment: right but as soon as I do that then do a `git checkout` to  my intended branch then I get the same error again

Comment: Try 

1. git fetch origin master

2. git reset --hard FETCH_HEAD

3. git clean -df

Comment: Or do a `git clone <url>` rather than doing a `git init` with an empty directory

Answer (score 2):

If you call `git pull` on a non git repository, you will get the error.

Steps to resolve the error:

1. `git clone`
2. `cd` directory of the repository you cloned.
3. `git init`
4. Now you can either `git pull` or `git checkout branchname`

Answer (score 0):

I am on a Windows machine and using WSL with Ubuntu. For me the solution was simply setting the git env variable the prompts errors on

```
export GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM=1
```